# How to make a thread sleep from another thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling

I have two threads of execution(say Thread1 and Thread2). Thread2 is listening for a particular event and as the event occurs it wants to stop execution of Thread1 and trigger an action. After it is done with the action it needs to continue the execution of Thread1 from where it stopped.

What kind of approach should I take to do this in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make another thread sleep in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508278/how-to-make-another-thread-sleep-in-java)

Answer (score 8):

The clean way to do it, IMHO, is to make Thread1 regularly poll some state variable to see if it has been asked to pause. If it's been asked to pause, then it should suspend its execution, waiting for some lock to be released.

Thread2 should ask Thread1 to pause by changing the value of the shared state variable, then potentialy wait for Thread1 to accept the pause request, then execute its action and release the lock on which Thread1 is waiting.

In short, the two threads must collaborate. There is no way that I'm aware of to pause a thread cleanly without its collaboration.

Answer (score 5):

You (of course) need a reference to the thread you wish to stop. You can pause it by calling the 'suspend' method: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend() on the thread.
Similarly you can call 'resume' to let the thread run again.

However, be aware that this is extremely prone to dead-lock problems since you have no idea where the thread is stopped.

Comment: suspend is deprecated (same with resume)

Comment: Sure it is deprecated, but it does exactly what the poster asks for. I am not going to judge his code from one short question. There may be very good reasons to do what he does.

Comment: There is no reason for downvoting. Suspending/resuming is the right pattern and we can't blame Matthias for the bad implementation in Java. **And** - Matthias added the warning in his answer. Showing that he is fully aware, that the methods are depracated and why it is so. We *still* can use the methods but we have to choose the environment very carefully.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need some sort of synchronization between threads. I suppose you want `T1` not to go to sleep, but wait until `T2` performs action. In such scenario, you could use any synchronization primitives Java provides. For example `synchronized` keyword:

```
class T1 implements Runnable {
  private final Object lock;

  public T1(Object lock) {
    this.lock = lock;
  }

  public function run() {
    while(!currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      waitForEvent();
      synchronized (lock) {
        // here T2 sleeps and wait until we perform event processing
      }
    }
  }
}

class T2 implements Runnable {
  private final Object lock;

  public T1(Object lock) {
    this.lock = lock;
  }

  public function run() {
    while(!currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      synchronized (lock) {
        // do some work and release lock
      }
    }
  }
}

Object lock = new Object();
new Thread(new T1(lock)).start();
new Thread(new T2(lock)).start();
```

And btw, methods `Thread#stop()`, `Thread#suspend()` and `Thread#resume()` are deprecated and it's not recommended to use them.

Answer (score 1):

use join in thread 2, read more here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Comment: join will not pause the referenced thread. It will wait until the thread has stopped executing and continue the waiting thread afterwards.

Comment: thanks, I remeber it wrong. join must be used in thread 1 which is not the question here.

Comment: `join` is not an option here, because neither thread 1 nor thread 2 will die (that's my understanding - thread 2 will continue listening, will it?)

Comment: I see the problem now `join` is probably not the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the other thread in `Thread2` and pause it.
But the real question is why you need two thread if they have to wait for each other to run ?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend() is deprecated.

Comment: Agreed - sounds like you may be misusing threads and your architecture may need an overhaul

Comment: Didn't mention `suspend` here.

Comment: (-1) because (a) we don't want to *pause* thread 2, (b) `pause` is not a method in `Thread` and (c) the *real* question is asked above.

Comment: That should cover it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: @Andreas_D I didn't use the verb 'pause' to refer to any method.