# Calling sleep on one thread is sleeping all my threads (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a vector of workers, each with their own thread, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
    {
        workers.addElement(new Worker(this, i));
        Thread t = new Thread(workers.elementAt(i));
        workerThreads.addElement(t);
        t.start();
    }
```

Each worker has its number in the vector, and when I need to stop a thread, I do this:

```
fp.workerThreads.elementAt(number).sleep(move.amount*1000);
```

However, even though I think I'm calling sleep on a single thread, it's stopping all of the worker threads in my vector. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what are the indications that all threads are sleeping? what are the indications they are running? all this code shows is how you have created the list of workers, but we don't know anything about workers or how you use them.

Comment: NO, it is not.  You are drawing an incorrect conclusion from the symptoms you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to do here is to call sleep on one of your worker object from the main thread.

```
fp.workerThreads.elementAt(number).sleep(move.amount*1000);
```

If you have to sleep in one of your worker threads. You will have to make sure you are calling the Thread.sleep() method from the thread you are trying to put to sleep. As you can see Thread.sleep is a static method and it doesn't care on which thread object you are calling a sleep on but which is your current thread. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm aware that Thread.sleep() is static, which is why I have an array of worker threads and I'm calling sleep() on a specific element in that vector. Is that what you mean?

Comment: So if Thread.sleep is static , There is only one method for all the thread objects. And it doesn't make any difference if you are calling it on any object. Thread.sleep() wouldnt know which thread object is calling sleep. it will sleep the thread which is making a call to the method.  So in your case I think you are calling it from the main thread. thats why main thread is sleeping

Comment: You can't call sleep() on a specific object, precisly *because* sleep is static. A static method if always called on the class. Java lets you make the call using an object of that class instead of the class itself (a rather confusing feature), but the call ignores the object. (It *must* ignore the object, since a static method has no 'this' reference.)

Comment: Usually your compiler will warn you when you call it like this (IMO, it could have been an error in the language spec). To think of it another way, the code above is identical to simply `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Please check  this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506537/how-to-make-a-thread-sleep-from-another-thread-in-java

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically *wrong*, but it is horrible:

```
Thread t = ...;
...
t.sleep();
```

It's not "wrong" because the compiler will let you do it.  It's horrible because it's misleading:  It looks like the the programmer thinks the sleep() call will something to thread t.  But that's not true at all.

IMO it's one of the biggest mistakes that the designers of the Java language made when they let you write that.  If your program's going to call sleep*, then do it like this:

```
Thread.sleep();
```

---

*But why call sleep() at all?  Unless it's for educational purposes, a Java program that calls Thread.sleep() either contains a re-invented wheel, or else it's sleeping for some inappropriate reason.  (Hint:  If your program has a synchronization problem, you can't fix it with sleep().  All you can do is make the problem much less likely to be found during testing, and therefore that much more likely to happen in the field when it finally does happen.)