# Sleep inner thread without sleeping outer thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, mina

I have a main Mina handler thread is processing and in that thread i made another thread and set it to sleep for specified time. Now i want that this inner thread sleep independently without blocking Handler thread.
following is sample code.

```
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {
        Integer tts = 5000; 
        Thread sleepThread = new Thread(obj);
        sleepThread.sleep(tts);
}
```

currently it is blocking main Handler thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make another thread sleep in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508278/how-to-make-another-thread-sleep-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep()` is a static method, so calling `sleepThread.sleep(tts)` is the same as  `Thread.sleep(tts)`. Hence your current thread is just sleeping.

You can't cause another thread to sleep by calling a method on its `Thread` object. At a push, you could set a flag on the object and your thread could check for the presence of that flag and behave accordingly.

Comment: @Rizstien You can't. Flag setting is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    final int tts = 5000; 
    Thread sleepThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(tts);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };
    sleepThread.start();
```