# Java's Thread sleep method not behaving as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

i want to sleep one thread on my propram,but it put two thread to sleep,so what's my problem,please help?

```
public class TestWait extends Thread{
    static TestWait t1;
    static TestWait t2;



    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                t1.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        t1 = new TestWait();
        t2 = new TestWait();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
    }

}
```

Comment: read the documentation for `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you have a warning in `t1.sleep()`:

`Thread.sleep(int)` pauses the current threat, so as `run()` implementation is shared by both objects, both of them are paused. You can change it and do something like this:

```
public class TestWait extends Thread{
    static TestWait t1;
    static TestWait t2;

    private boolean flag

    public TestWait(boolean wait) {
         this.flag=wait;
    }

    public void run() {


     while(true) {
            try {
                if (flag) {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
        t1 = new TestWait(true);
        t2 = new TestWait(false);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
    }

}
```

Comment: so i need put my sleep() in body of run() method of thread i want to use?

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep` is `static` method which makes thread which invokes it sleep for amount of millisecconds. Your code

```
t1.sleep(10000);
```

in reality is same as

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: i'm sorry,but,if i want t1 to sleep and t2 keep working,what should i do?

Comment: @user3429135 Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508278/how-to-make-another-thread-sleep-in-java

Answer (score 1):

That method puts the "currently executing thread to sleep".  It should not be called against an instance that way.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can invoke static methods using a reference to a class instance, even if this reference is `null`... If you have a static method `s` in class `A`, then all of these work:

```
final A a = new A();
final A nullA = null;

A.s(); // via class
a.s(); // via non null reference
nullA.s(); // via null reference
```

And [`Thread.sleep()` is static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

In order to avoid confusions, don't use this method but use `TimeUnit` instead:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
```