# How to make JVM hang for a given time period?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am trying to simulate GC in my local environment. Is there any way I can make JVM hang for 5 mins?

Comment: @duffymo What about the other JVM threads that spawn on execution? They won't be sleeping.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hang'? You can pause the current thread with the `Thread.sleep()` command.

Comment: When JVM is handling GC what happens? Same scenario I am trying in my local environment. Thread.sleep makes only one thread sleep. What about remaining threads?

Comment: I know this wasn't your question, but in past I have seen GC related issues get addressed by tweaking Garbage Collection parameters. Correct parameters can make a LOT of difference.



Example (this is from 2010, but you will get some idea): 

http://www.tikalk.com/java/garbage-collection-serial-vs-parallel-vs-concurrent-mark-sweep/

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a Linux system (most other unixes will also have this), you can do

```
pkill -STOP java; sleep $(( 5 * 60 )); pkill -CONT java
```

to pause all java process for 5 minutes.

```
pkill -TSTP java; sleep $(( 5 * 60 )); pkill -CONT java
```

is slightly less agressive.

But this will be **nowhere like a garbage collector break**.

Comment: This sounds very good idea. I'll try it Monday. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I don't think it will work anything like what you need... simulating a GC pause by stopping the process will help you nothing IMHO. Instead, simulate memory leaks.

Comment: During GC jvm will consume all available processors, so this is not a good simulation of long GC.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate a very long stop-the-world event on almost all HotSpot JVMs.
HotSpot doesn't put [safepoints](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html) into counted int loops, because it assumes that they will terminate just "fast enough"(In this case server compiler will generate more optimal loop code). Even a stop-the-world will have to wait until this loop will finish. In this method we have very tight loop which do small but expensive computations without safepoint polling.

```
public static double slowpoke(int iterations) {
    double d = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < iterations; j++) {
        d += Math.log(Math.E * j);
    }
    return d;
}
```

For example you can use this code:

```
public class SafepointTest {

    public static double slowpoke(int iterations) {
        double d = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < iterations; j++) {
            d += Math.log(Math.E * j);
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double sideEffect = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    sideEffect = slowpoke(999999999);
                }
                System.out.println("result = " + sideEffect);
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while (true){
                    System.out.println("Delay " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp));
                    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //trigger stop-the-world 
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

As a result:

```
Delay 5
Delay 4
Delay 30782
Delay 21819
Delay 21966
Delay 22812
Delay 22264
Delay 21988
```

In order to increase delay just change argument value for `slowpoke(int iterations)` function.

Here is useful diagnostic commands:

- `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` this will actually report pause time for all safepoints into GC log. Unfortunately output from this option lacks timestamps.
- `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` this two options will force JVM to report reason and timings after each safepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Develop builds of the hotspot JVM have an option called `UseLoopSafepoints`.

Using this you can do the following:

1. disable loop safepoints
2. write a spin wait loop that increments a `long`. this should prevent the VM from reaching a safepoint until the loop exits
3. have another thread initiate a GC or call `Thread.getAllStackTraces()`, this should trigger a safepoint

Together those things will suspend all VM threads because they will try to reach a safepoint, but the safepoint will be blocked by your spin loop.
In effect this should behave similarly to a long GC safepoint due to excessive GC work.

Note: I haven't tested this.

Comment: I have provided an useful example for any HotSpot JVM

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you https://github.com/giltene/HeapFragger. Gil Tene normally knows what he is doing.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>JVM GC is designed in a way that your application shouldn't "Hang" but from what I understand, you want all threads to sleep:</strike>

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
for(Thread thread : threadSet) {
    if(thread == Thread.currentThread) //Make sure this one doesn't sleep.
        continue;
    thread.sleep({{Time in ms}});
}
Thread.sleep({{Time in ms}}); //Now we can make this thread sleep.
```

Totally untested.
You can also force garbage collection: `System.gc();`

**Edit:** After some research, I don't think this is possible:
[How to make another thread sleep in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508278/how-to-make-another-thread-sleep-in-java)

Comment: You can't force garbage collection; this is merely a suggestion.

Comment: 1TB of RAM? That's all the GC is going to free.

Comment: `thread.sleep()` doesn't work, because you're not actually calling an instance method, just a static method (which should cause a compiler warning).  `thread.suspend()` might work.

Comment: @SeetaRamayyaVadali, 1TB of ram is a lot. The most advanced collectors in hotspot can deal with maybe 100GB (depending on memory bandwidth and available thread count) under good conditions without excessive pause times. You might want to look into Azul's Zing VM and their pauseless collector if you have to deal with such huge heaps.

Comment: @the8472 We know and we are considering Azul part